# Remote Xfce session in a separate console?

Tags: xorg, xfce, ssh-tunneling, remote-desktop

I have the following setups:

A netbook with Xubuntu 14.04 and desktop PC with Debian 7. I can connect from netbook to desktop through SSH. I want to start a separate X server on netbook and host on it a whole separate Xfce 4 session from a desktop PC.

So the sessions layout must be following

#### netbook

- X display :0 (one at alt+ctrl+f7) - own Xfce session, that works
  locally on a netbook
- X display :1 (or any other) - Xfce session that
  runs on a remote desktop PC

#### desktop

- X display :0 - own Xfce session, that works locally on a desktop
- And without X display - remote Xfce session, that shows on a netbook

#### How can I do it?

I had searched all over internet and could not find solution that will fit my needs. Also, if anyone knows some resource that have a nice explanation of a whole X windows system and how to control it - I'll be happy to read about it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a desktop manager like `xdm`, `gdm` or `kdm`, configure it for remote access via XDMCP. Once the desktop manager on the desktop PC is set up to accept remote connections you do

```
Xorg :1 vt8 -query <put desktop PC address here>
```

on your netbook.

**KDM setup**

Depending on your distribution and version, the name and location of the config files may change. For a Debian 7 you would have to put the following into `/etc/kde4/kdm/kdmrc`: (It may even already be in there, but as comments.)

```
[Xdmcp]
Enable=true
Xaccess=/etc/kde4/kdm/Xaccess
Willing=/etc/kde4/kdm/Xwilling
```

With these settings you restart kdm, `/etc/init.d/kdm restart`. You can check if it works using `netstat -ulepn | grep kdm`. It should show `kdm` listening on port 177.

**GDM setup**

In `/etc/gdm3/daemon.conf` you will an empty section `[xdmcp]`. In the end, it must read

```
[xdmcp]
Enable=true
```

Restart gdm with `/etc/init.d/gdm3 restart` and check if its listening on port 177 using `netstat -ulepn | grep gdm`.

**XDM setup**

IIRC, `xdm` will listen on port 177 out of the box, but is not configured to accept remote queries. You will have to edit `/etc/X11/xdm/Xaccess` and make your netbook known to xdm so it will serve it. The quickest win is by just putting the following as the only line in `/etc/X11/xdm/Xaccess`:

```
*
LISTEN *
```

It means xdm will serve all clients requesting a session (first line). The second line tells XDM to listen on all interfaces and addresses for incoming requests. The second line should be redundant, but I really don't know how xdm works these days. I think you can also just put the FQDN or IP-address of your netbook on a single line. This should allow only this one host to get a session. I'm sure the man page knows...

Restarting and testing using `netstat` is analogous to the other two.

Comment: I dont have a direct connection with desktop PC, only SSH tunel through a router. Should I use 127.0.0.1 in a `<put desktop PC address here>` placeholder? And forward port 177 over my tunel?

Comment: @Vasilly.Prokopyev: oh ... that's what you meant. Well, when setting up the ssh connection, you can add `-L177:127.0.01:177` and `-R6001:127.0.0.1:6001` to the `ssh` call, to make this work over SSH. However, in that scenario you could just install `x2goserver` on your desktop pc and `x2goclient` on your netbook. I do believe the client can be full screen.